# Is it possible to to type 16 bit unicodes with Unicode Hex Input?

Tags: keyboard, macos, internationalization, unicode

I want to be able to type Unicodes that have more than 4 digits, such as  (1D11E) or  (1D122), but macOS only registers the first 4 digits and types the wrong character.
I know on windows this can be achieved by modifying a registry entry or something, and I was wondering if there was a way to do the same on macOS. 
I don't want to rely on the character viewer to type those characters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, activate the Unicode Hex input source and hold down the option key while you type the 8 characters of the UTF-16 version of your 5 digit codepoint.  You may have to look that up on Google.  1d11e is d834dd1e